# How to use NSUserDefaults with property getter and setter in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save and retrieve a variable in memory directly from its setter and getter property but the getter result in an infinite loop and the app crash  with error message :

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x10049b9a0).
>   The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

What could be the reason and how to do this properly?

```
  class Task {

    let memory = NSUderDefaults.standardUserDefaults() 
    var taskList: [String: Double]{

    get {

        let savedList = memory.dictionaryForKey("SavedTasksList") as? [String: Double] ?? [String: Double]()

        return savedList
    }

    set (tasks){

        memory.setObject(tasks, forKey: "SavedTasksList")

    }

}
}
```

Comment: what is memory? Where is your code to store data in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Basically this code does not cause an infinite loop. How is `taskList` used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
class Task {

    var taskList: [String: Double]{

        get {
            return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("SavedTasksList") as? [String: Double] ?? [String: Double]()
        }

        set {
            let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            defaults.setObject(newValue, forKey: "SavedTasksList")
            defaults.synchronize()
        }
    }
}
```

Or in Swift 3:

```
class Task {

    var taskList: [String: Double]{

        get {
            return UserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("SavedTasksList") as? [String: Double] ?? [String: Double]()
        }

        set {
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            defaults.setObject(newValue, forKey: "SavedTasksList")
            defaults.synchronize()  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works great. Any idea why my implementation didn't work? I had memory define as NSUderDefaults.standardUserDefaults

Answer (score 0):

In your example, @irkinosor, you are not calling synchronize() on your instance of the NSUserDefaults called "memory" when performing an update/set.  That could be a factor.